# How to apply the bootstrap 3 modal animation transition effect in bootstrap 4

Tags: animation, modal-dialog

In bootstrap 3 I liked the transition animation effect that came by default when the modal window appeared:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#live-demo

But in bootstrap 4 this effect has disappeared, I have been trying to do it manually but it does not come out the same, there is a way to activate it again in such a way that it remains the same as in 3, here we can see how it has no effect when showing the modal:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, I saw in the version 4.0 still working the modal like bootstrap 3, but in the version 4.6 is different, then I take with inspector browser and the code when click in the modal is the same I'm putting here, you can try in this page:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo

The code that you put in your style.css:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
}
.modal.show .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
.fade.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I agree, I have edited this post with more information.